# GNOME Boxes: What is needed for 3D acceleration?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 3d, gnome-boxes

**Background:**
Running Kubuntu in a GNOME Boxes virtual machine has missing desktop switching effects.

Elsewhere, it has been suggested that this may be due to missing 3D acceleration. In VirtualBox with 3D acceleration, the effects show (without it, KDE complains).

The [GNOME Boxes website](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eshaunm/help.gnome.org/gnome-boxes/3d-acceleration.html) states that  3D Acceleration is supported if both guest and host virtual machines support it. I therefore hope to make my guest and host support 3D acceleration.

**Problem**: GNOME Boxes does not show a 3D acceleration options for the virtual machine. I have tried Boxes 40, 41 and 42 (alpha).

**Question:** What are the prerequisites for guest and host VMs to support GNOME Boxes 3D acceleration?

Comment: There's a line `<acceleration accel3d="no"/>` in the Libvrt configuration line for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but changing to `yes` (and restarting the VM) appears to have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by following the your link. Here's a screenshot of where I found it:

[image: Screenshot of 3d acceleration option in GNOME Boxes]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. Alas, this options did not show for me, and what I tried to ask was what it takes for it to show.