# No Animations in 22.04

Tags: virtualization, 22.04, animations

I am testing out Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish in a virtual machine, and I realized that there are almost no animations. The scrolling isn't smooth, there are barely any animations in the DE, and there aren't 1:1 trackpad gestures (they follow your fingers) like there should be. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it being in a virtual machine, because I gave it 6GB RAM and 50 GiB disk space.

One of the only reasons I am testing 22.04 is because I was curious about if the animations were different and I wanted to see the 1:1 trackpad gestures. How can I get the animations back?

**EDIT:**

- I am using the virtual machine manager called GNOME Boxes
- Host system: Ubuntu 20.04
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® Iris(R) Plus Graphics (ICL GT2)
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7 CPU @ 1.30GHz × 8
- 8GB RAM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GNOME Boxes: What is needed for 3D acceleration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389151/gnome-boxes-what-is-needed-for-3d-acceleration) You have not told us what kind of GPU your host computer has.

Comment: @user68186 This doesn't answer my question because for some reason there is no option for 3d acceleration

Comment: This probably means your host computer does not have the GPU to do it. Or Gnome Boxes can't access it for some reason.

Comment: @user68186 ...so I can't have animations? That makes no sense because if I'm visualizing an operating system I should have animations. Do I have to enable 3d acceleration somewhere in my system/bios?

Comment: I have no idea. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1413041/edit) and provide the details about the host system where Gnome Boxes is installed. Try something else like [QEMU](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-qemu-kvm-on-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/) or VirtualBox.

Comment: @user68186 Alright, the edits have been made

Comment: The host hardware seems good enough for me, but I don't use Gnome Boxes.

Comment: @user68186 Yeah, there's just no option. I tried editing the config file and when i saved the file, boxes told me that 3d acceleration isn't supported. "Failed to save domain configuration: Failed to set domain configuration: unsupported configuration: qxl 3d acceleration is not supported"